# Rails - unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end - Savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, savon

I am trying to passing the data below into Savon to send as an XML.

Works perfectly fine when passing one item in.

When I add an each statement for when multiple items are added the following error is created:

```
syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end
  'SalesOrder' => [
```

Code that does work:

```
new_or = {

"Order" => {
  "AccountCode" => '#{current_user.accode}',
  "Properties" => {
    "PropertyItem" => [
      {
        "Name" => "Foo",
        "Value" => "Bar",
      },
      {
        "Name" => "Colour",
        "Value" => "Green",
      }
    ]
  }
  "Items" => { 
    'SalesOrder' => {
       'sku' => "SKU-100",
        'Quantity' => 10,
        'Price' => 10.78,
     }
}

} #Close_Order

} #Close new_or
```

Code that doesn't work:

```
new_or = {

"Order" => {
  "AccountCode" => '#{current_user.accode}',
  "Properties" => {
    "PropertyItem" => [
      {
        "Name" => "Foo",
        "Value" => "Bar",
      },
      {
        "Name" => "Colour",
        "Value" => "Green",
      }
    ]
  }
  "Items" => { 
    @order.items.each do |item|
       'SalesOrder' => [
        {
          'sku' => item.sku,
          'Quantity' => item.qtny,
          'Price' => item.price,
        },
      ],
  end
}

} #Close_Order

} #Close new_or
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: By the way, both of your codes are invalid as Ruby.

Comment: "Code that does work" - I don't think so. It's all kinds of broken. As is the second one.

Comment: @sovalina That is a typo as I had to rewrite it into the question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev As noted this is a typo when typing the question

Comment: @Stewart: when you assert "this code works", you better post code that __actually__ works (see [mcve]). Also, now that you _know_ you have posted invalid code, you should fix it instead of dismissing comments with "was a typo, doesn't matter".

Comment: Looks better now.  I'm 99.99% sure that `Order => ` should be `"Order" => `, but at least it is valid parseable ruby now (provided that constant `Order` exists)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Cheers for the feedback, Have updated it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I would point out is that you should use `map` instead of `each` in this scenario because otherwise it will not return the captured structure of the block, only the original `Item` records.

Second, there are quite a lot of syntax issues in your statements, some probably typos in the question since you say that the first section is working, even though there are some issues there as well. But study the following which I assume is the result you are after.

```
"Items" => @order.items.map { |item|
    {
        'SalesOrder' => {
            'sku' => item.sku,
            'Quantity' => item.qtny,
            'Price' => item.price
        }
    }
}
```

That will result in the following example

```
"Items" => [
    {
        'SalesOrder' => {
            'sku' => 10,
            'Quantity' => 100,
            'Price' => 999
        }
    },
    {
        'SalesOrder' => {
            'sku' => 20,
            'Quantity' => 200,
            'Price' => 1299
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks DanneManne, Worked perfectly have just read up on Map / each and can see where it was going wrong. - Thanks.